# How do you express the idea that someone drives (rides) their car (bike) in the opposite direction?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request, sentence-request

Suppose that in the US, where right-hand traffic is the practice, someone is driving on the left-hand side of the road while they should be on the right-hand side.

How do you describe this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They would be driving **against the traffic**. This is also called wrong-way driving or counterflow driving. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrong-way_driving

Comment: Where I live (UK) this action is very often called 'driving on the wrong side of the road'.