# How do we express a vehicle on a lane moves in a wrong direction?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

A street  might have 2 opposite flows of traffic. It is divided into 2 halves or 2 lanes. One half/lane allows traffic to move one direction and the other half/lane allows traffic to move the opposite direction.

But a street might just have 1 flow of traffic. All vehicles must move in that one direction.

On one lane, a vehicle must follow the direction of that lane.

**How do we express a vehicle on a lane moves in a wrong direction?**

Suppose you are driving your car on one lane of a street with 2  lanes. Another car that is also on the same lane as yours is moving towards you.

Is it correct to say "**that car is going the opposite direction**"?

That would be confused because the listeners might think that car is on the other lane of your lane.

Comment: Does [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/324747/139980) help?

Comment: The situation you describe isn't quite clear. If two cars are going in opposite directions, one is heading north and the other south (for example). This is normal on a street that isn't one-way.

Comment: @KateBunting, you can look at this picture https://vyha18.github.io/video/WrongDirec.png. If I drove like that I would get a fine for sure

Comment: I wasn't sure whether you were talking about a two-way street or a one-way one with two lanes. The car that is _going the wrong way_ is moving _towards_ the other vehicles, not _opposite_ them.

Comment: We say vehicle in a lane, not on one.

Answer (score 6):

The car is driving (or being driven) the wrong way. The driver is a wrong-way driver.

[Wiktionary *wrong-way driver*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wrong-way_driver)
"A driver who drives in the unpermitted direction, particularly on a highway."

A search on "wrong-way driver" will find many examples on Google.

I don't understand the word "offsite" in your question.

Comment: We even have red and white signs that let people know they have erred.  https://www.google.com/search?q=wrong+way+sign&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS982US982&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiaraHgmN36AhX1g4kEHYdZD4gQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1920&bih=937&dpr=1